# Syntax for writing a method that accepts an object that has a specific method

Tags: generics, scala

I want to write a generic helper method:

```
def using(closeable: [B has close() method], callback: [B has close() method] => A): A {
  try {
    callback(closeable)
  } finally {
    closeable.close()
  }
}
```

with the intent being that I can use this with anything that has a close() method:

```
using(new FileInputStream(...)) {
  stream => stream.read()
}

using(dataSource.getConnection) {
  conn => using(conn.createStatement()) {
    statement => using(statement.executeQuery("...")) {
      rs => rs.getString(1)
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is how this is named, such that I could have searched for the syntax myself, and the syntax itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debilski is right, the syntax for that would be `closable: { def close() }`

Edit: Here's a link to an alternative [Scala implementation of the .NET like using construct](http://code.alexblack.ca/creating-cs-using-statement-in-scala) you want to use based on an object and it's apply method.

Answer (score 8):

To give it in full

```
type Closeable = {def close() }
def using[A,B](a: A with Closeable)(f: A => B) =
 try { f(a) } finally { a.close() }
```

(you may also write `A {def close()}` rather than `A with Closeable`)

A test:

```
case class X(i: Int) { def close() = println("closed") }
using(X(3)){x => println("i is " + x.i) }
```

output:

> i is 3
>
> closed

Answer (score 5):

This is called a *structural type*.